What is the methond for altering the drush `core:status` command?
I am attempting to alter the drush core:status command to add additional information. I am following the docs here: https://www.drush.org/13.x/commands/#altering-command-info
Here is my alter function:
public function alterCommandInfo(CommandInfo $commandInfo, $commandFileInstance) {
  if ($commandInfo->getName() === 'core:status') {
    // A debugger never enters this conditional.
  }
}

A debugger pauses when entering alterCommandInfo(), so I have confirmed my code is called, however the value of commandInfo->getName() is never core:status, so I am unable to alter the command. It seems that core commands are not passed through the alter hook. Does this imply a bug, or is there an alternate way of altering core Drush commands.

So debug $commandInfo->getName() what is it then?

Hundreds of them, including most of the list of commands that are seen when running drush, as well as some additional ones like *. But never core:status or in fact anything related to status at all, that isn't a different command, for example search-api-status. I set my debugger to pause on any command that has 'status' in it, and I viewed them all, but none were the command I was looking for. Even other custom commands I have in the project are alterable.

Also see https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/320343/2800 for what sounds like a working alternative
